# Set UPPER just before a space with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a question about `UPPER()` function with MySQL.
I have a sample which look like in the same column :

> lastname firstname

And I would like to handle this column in order to get :

> LASTNAME firstname

If I want to get : `LASTNAME FIRSTNAME` I can do that :

```
UPDATE llx_societe SET `nom` = UPPER( `nom` );
```

==> My question is : How I can just set Upper the lastname ?

Thank you !

Comment: is the lastname and firstname in separate columns?

Comment: No, the same column. Just separate by space value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `substring_index`:

```
update llx_societe set nom = concat(upper(substring_index(nom, ' ', 1)), ' ', substring_index(nom, ' ', -1));
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f138c/1) demo here.

Comment: And `name` corresponding at table name ?

Comment: Yep I tried it and it works so thank you so much ! I didn't know this kind of syntax and the demo website ;)

Answer (score 0):

My script :

```
UPDATE llx_societe SET nom=CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTR(u.nom, 1, INSTR(u.nom, ' ')-1)), SUBSTR(u.nom, INSTR(u.nom, ' ')+1)
```

Answer (score -2):

EDIT

```
update llx_societe 
set nom = concat(UPPER( left(nom,locate(' ',nom )-1)),
    ' ',substring(nom,locate(' ',nom )+1,length(nom)))
```

Comment: It's the same column. The column is called `nom` and looks like lastname firstname ^^ So doesn't work. Else I already found this solution.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers.